# How to enable text copy in html

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, css, google-chrome

I am using widgetLayoutService and have many html pages. Somehow text selection is disabled within html pages only in chrome. I want to enable it for few html pages. I try to use following css style and apply on required pages main div but it still unable to to select and copy any text using mouse. Here is my css:

```
.force-select {
-webkit-user-select:text !important;
-webkit-touch-callout:default !important;
-webkit-user-select:text !important;
-moz-user-select:text !important;
-ms-user-select:text !important;
user-select:text !important;
```

}

Can someone tell me is there any other alternative to enable text can be copy from mouse in chrome.

Comment: Can you show us your html structure please. Also check the css to see if somewhere you can find -webkit-user-select: none !important;
It could be an Order of Specification issue

Comment: I have verified there is no place where i have disabled this but still it not allow to select text to copy.

Comment: Did you try to optimise this class. Maybe you no need for 6 variant.